# The most powerful inner model and a $\Delta^2_1$ well-ordering of the reals

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory, inner-model-theory

With the current research, it seems that we are in a position to get extremely powerful absoluteness theorems (like $\Sigma^2_0$-absoluteness, [$\Sigma^2_1$-absoluteness, $\Sigma^2_2$, $\diamondsuit_G$](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212406),...) and eventually stop at $\diamondsuit_G$, although inner model theory does not reach that high.

On the other hand, it seems that stronger absolutes can also to search for higher well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$; does this stop somewhere?

- **Is there an inner model has a $\Delta^2_0$/$\Delta^2_1$/$\Delta^2_2$/$\Delta^2_3$-good well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$?**
- **Assume $\mathsf{Ultimate-L}$ + [Woodin's Perfect Theory](https://doi.org/10.1142/S021906131100102X). Where will the well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ stop in the hierarchy?**

Comment: Well, $L$ has a $\Delta^1_2$-definable well-order of $\mathbb{R}$, so it is clearly $\Delta^2_0$. But I guess this is not what you want, and the right question you wanted to ask might be something like "An inner model admitting large cardinals with a definable well-order of $\mathbb{R}$," which is a major problem in inner model therory.